How to get value from SQL View in wordpress
I am trying to minimize the amount of queries I'm pulling on each page. We have a dynamic review counter on the footer of our website that has to call the same query twice. I created a shortcode that remade it. Shortcode works but the last part that needs to be done is actually grabbing the two column/row values from the SQL View I've created.
Here is the format of the view:



count
rating




2056
4.81



The view is automatically created from the comments & comment meta table and I used an average/count function. This view is good to go.
Here is my current code for the shortcode:
function find_site_review_data() {
    //Get Values from the Site_Reviews View
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM Site_Reviews_Summary WHERE rating > 0', $average);
    
    $average = 0;
    $count = 1234;
    
    $output = '
    <div class="store-reviews-box">
    <img width="300" height="51" src="https://cdn.roofingdirect.com/2019/03/roofing-drect-logo.png" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-image-1120" alt="Roofing Direct">
    <div class="rating-bar">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="https://cdn.roofingdirect.com/2024/01/cusrev_logo.png" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-image-150836" alt="Footer: No Value Stack |  | Roofing Direct" srcset="https://cdn.roofingdirect.com/2024/01/cusrev_logo.png 150w, https://cdn.roofingdirect.com/2024/01/cusrev_logo.png 100w, https://cdn.roofingdirect.com/2024/01/cusrev_logo.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 150px) 100vw, 150px">
        <div class="rating-scale">
            <div class="star"></div>
            <div class="star"></div>
            <div class="star"></div>
            <div class="star"></div>
            <div class="star"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <p id="avg"><span id="avg-fill">'. $average .'</span> Rating</p>
        <p id="count">(<span id="count-fill">'. number_format($count,0,".",",") .'</span> Reviews)</p>
    </div>
</div>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('site_review_box', 'find_site_review_data');

I've attempted get_var(), get_row() and such but unsure if the $wpdb will work since this is not a table nor a default wordpress table with the wp_ prefix. What would be the correct syntax to get the singular row value of whatever column I want? This will be repeated for count but I just need to do one at least to get started.
Also looked at this thread but still unsure how to fix it to use my View: Wordpress How to get value from get_results function

Nevermind, guess I wasn't writing in the full line. Got it figured out. For any others who may come upon this, here was the answer:
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM Site_Reviews_Summary', ARRAY_A);

$average = $query['rating'];
$count = $query['count'];

